# iTunes Connect - beta testing - push new build before external user accepts initial invite?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I have pushed a version of my beta app to the itunes connect beta app service.  I have gone through the beta app approval process, and have been accepted.  I sent invites to a bunch of external users.  I have pushed another version/build of my application.  Not all of my external users have accepted the initial invitation for the application.  I have had to disable the old version before I could push the new one into the approval process, which does not allow the previously invited users (ones that had not accepted ) to get the previous version or even see the app as available.  I did change the version (from 0.1.3 to 0.1.4) if I only changed the build number instead of the version, would my previous external users be able to access the previous build while in the approval process for the new build?

Answer (score 0):

Apple says that only one of the versions can be enabled for TestFlight beta testing.

If you upload a newer version, then you need do disable the old version of you app. Then only you can share new version.
If you want the old version back, then you need to disable new version and enable old version.

In short, only one version of your app will be active.

Comment: how do you disable old versions?

Comment: Go to pre release section of the application. Then there will be a switch "TestFlight Beta Testing" for every version. You can select which version should be enabled.

Comment: can the users, that already installed the 'old' version of the app still use it, while the new version is being approved?
I have a bunch of users testing the old version and I don't want them to not be able to use the app for the period, while the new app is being approved for testing.

Comment: I didn't check that. But probably, the old installers must work until the provisioning profile get expired.